# Can PHP Includes be used to onClick load one page inside another

Tags: javascript, ajax

Need to load the content of one page inside another to simulate tabbed panels. The current methods I have tried do not work. Iframe does not readjust size to conform with the collapsible panels and with ajax the collapsible panels and calculating scripts do not work at all.

Testing area is located here

http://www.divethegap.com/scuba-diving-programmes-dive-the-gap/programme-pages/dahab-divemaster/test.php?cat=17

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: what ajax solution have you tried? using jQuery to load the contents of a page should be pretty straightforward...

Comment: I don't see any problems in Opera

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do from that link and your question. Can you describe in detail what should happen when you click where?

Comment: Take a look at this page
http://www.divethegap.com/scuba-diving-programmes-dive-the-gap/dahab-divemaster-training.html
Now click on one of the buttons at the bottom that says Open Water, Advanced Open Water (ect...). A booking page loads up with lots of options which are all individual wordpress posts. You can see how it all works. 
Now what I want to do is load those options onto the preceeding page using those buttons you clicked on to get there as tabs loading the options and the calculation scripts below them on click.
Dynamic Drive ajax script does not work.
Please Help.

Comment: I'm guessing [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) would be too simple here?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery tabs. This is not php specific.